# updating osx terminal after macport installation

Tags: terminal, osx-mavericks

I installed `macports` on my macbook pro and after the successful install, I tried typing in 'port' in a terminal tab that I had was already opened before the `macport` installation and it gave me the error "command not found"

When I opened another tab in the terminal and tried again, it worked. (It works in the new tab but does not work in the old one)

I am guessing that this has to do with the fact that the first tab was opened **before** the the `macport` **installation** took place.

**Just wanted to know how to refresh the terminal after I install something like `macports`.**

PS: I know that I can open a new tab and continue working but am just curious how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**General:** You can use the `reset` command:

```
reset
```

For more information run:

```
man reset
```

---

**MacPorts:** The `PATH` variable is set by the postflight script to append the MacPorts executable paths to the default path:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

The location of this line depends on your shell, the installer may use `.profile`, `.bash_login`, `.bash_profile`, `.tcshrc`, or `.cshrc`.

If you want these changes to take effect in the current Terminal window, you either need to execute this command manually:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Or if you know which file contains the line above, you can [source](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html) it. For example:

```
source ~/.profile
```